# How to close the menu when I click outside?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, twig, drupal-8

I created a menu with Bootstrap 4. Here is the HTML code :

```
{% block head %}
        <nav{{ navbar_attributes }}>
          {% if container_navbar %}
            <div class="container">
          {% endif %}

            {% if page.navigation_collapsible_first %}
              <div class="collapse-navbar-first">
                <div class="collapse bg-light navbar-collapse" id="CollapsingNavbarFirst">
                  {{ page.navigation_collapsible_first }}
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}

            {{ page.navigation_menu_first }}
            {{ page.navigation_notification_first }}
            {{ page.navigation_logo }}
            {{ page.navigation_notification_second }}
            {{ page.navigation_menu_second }}

            {% if page.navigation_collapsible_second %}
              <div class="collapse-navbar-second">
                <div class="collapse bg-light navbar-collapse" id="CollapsingNavbarSecond">
                  {{ page.navigation_collapsible_second }}
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}

          {% if container_navbar %}
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

I want the menu to close when I click outside. It works with the JS code below, but it also closes when I click in it. It must close only if I click outside :

```
  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#CollapsingNavbarFirst').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#CollapsingNavbarSecond').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
  });
```

Here is a page of my site to test. In the menu at the top right (the filter box), when you select an option from the drop-down menu, it closes. If you click a white space in the menu, it closes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple: if you want to close *.navbar-collapse* when you click outside *.navbar-collapse* just write that.

```
/// When you click everywhere in the document
$(document).click(function (event) {

  /// If *navbar-collapse* is not among targets of event
  if (!$(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse *')) {

    /// Collapse every *navbar-collapse*
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');

  }
});
```

You don't even need to use IDs

Comment: I just applied your code on my site but it does not solve the problem

Comment: If you want people to wite code for you you should provide an editable example, we are not writing code inside your project. My snippet should work in most cases, but I don't know what else you may have on your page. I'll edit my answer to cover more usecases, but there is no warranty that copypasted code from answers will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
    var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    if(elementMouseIsOver.id=="menu"){
      console.log("menu");
    }
    else{
      console.log("not menu");
    }
});
```

```css
#menu{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
.test{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<div id="menu"></div>
</div>
```